# How to resolve a JavaScript Syntax Error in adobe acrobat?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have been tasked with converting the forms for the court system I work for into fillable PDF's. I was asked to make the "address" field auto-populate depending on what choice was selected in the "Courtroom" dropdown list. I know nothing about coding so I searched forums until I found a walkthrough that contained this code

```
// Place all prepopulation data into a single data structure
var DeptData = { Accounting:{ contact: "Steala Damuni",
                              email: "accounting@mycomp.com",
                              deptnum: "cmp1234" },
                 Engineering:{ contact: "Frank N. Stien",
                              email: "engineering@mycomp.com",
                              deptnum: "eng1234" },
                 Marketing :{ contact: "Shelly Oughtbuks",
                              email: "marketing@mycomp.com",
                              deptnum: "mkt1234" },
                 ITSupport:{ contact: "Goah  Wei",
                              email: "it@mycomp.com",
                              deptnum: "its1234" }};
function SetFieldValues(cDeptName)
{
  this.getField("DeptContact").value = DeptData[cDeptName].contact;
  this.getField("DeptEmail").value = DeptData[cDeptName].email;
  this.getField("DeptNumber").value = DeptData[cDeptName].deptnum;
}
```

I tried changing the field names so they would match my form and got this

```
var DeptData = { South Division Dept. 1:{ address: "20520 68th Ave. W. Lynnwood WA 98036"},
               South Division Dept. 2:{ address: "20520 68th Ave W Lynnwood WA 98036"},
               South Division Dept. 3:{ address: "20520 68th Ave. W. Lynnwood WA 98036"},
               South Division Dept. 4:{ address: "20520 68th Ave. W. Lynnwood WA 98036"},
               Cascade Division Dept. 1:{ address: "415 E Burke Ave. Arlington WA 98223"},
               Cascade Division Dept. 2:{ address: "415 E Burke Ave. Arlington WA 98223"},
               Evergreen Division Dept. 1:{ address: "14414 179th Ave SE Monroe WA 98272"},
               Evergreen Division Dept. 2:{ address: "14414 179th Ave SE Monroe WA 98272"},
               Everett Division Courtroom 3A:{ address: "3000 Rockefeller Ave Everett WA 98201"},
               Everett Division Courtroom 3B:{ address: "3000 Rockefeller Ave Everett WA 98201"},
               Everett Division Courtroom 3C:{ address: "3000 Rockefeller Ave Everett WA 98201" }};

function SetFieldValues(cCourtroom)
{
  this.getField("address").value = DeptData[cCourtroom].address;
  
}
```

Thing is it keeps throwing up an error, "SyntaxError: missing : after property id 1: at line 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object keys have spaces, you need to put them into quotes like this:

```js
var DeptData = {
  "South Division Dept. 1": {
    address: "20520 68th Ave. W. Lynnwood WA 98036"
  },
  "South Division Dept. 2": {
    address: "20520 68th Ave W Lynnwood WA 98036"
  },
  "South Division Dept. 3": {
    address: "20520 68th Ave. W. Lynnwood WA 98036"
  },
  "South Division Dept. 4": {
    address: "20520 68th Ave. W. Lynnwood WA 98036"
  },
  "Cascade Division Dept. 1": {
    address: "415 E Burke Ave. Arlington WA 98223"
  },
  "Cascade Division Dept. 2": {
    address: "415 E Burke Ave. Arlington WA 98223"
  },
  "Evergreen Division Dept. 1": {
    address: "14414 179th Ave SE Monroe WA 98272"
  },
  "Evergreen Division Dept. 2": {
    address: "14414 179th Ave SE Monroe WA 98272"
  },
  "Everett Division Courtroom 3A": {
    address: "3000 Rockefeller Ave Everett WA 98201"
  },
  "Everett Division Courtroom 3B": {
    address: "3000 Rockefeller Ave Everett WA 98201"
  },
  "Everett Division Courtroom 3C": {
    address: "3000 Rockefeller Ave Everett WA 98201"
  }
};
```